# Perl command line autosplit vs / /

Tags: perl

I frequently use Perl autosplit instead of cut on the command line. I have hit a case where I have a lot of blanks that I need to preserve. According to the doc, the separator I need to specify is `/ /` because things like `' '` emulate awk's behavior stripping leading blanks etc.

My problem is it seems impossible to specify the `/ /` pattern on the command line. I tried quoting it in various ways but splitting end up occuring on the forward slash:

```
perl -F'/ /' -lane 'print "@F[3..$#F]"' input.txt
```

The following works as expected:

```
perl -lne '@ar = split / /; print "@ar[3..$#ar]"' input.txt
```

Why my autosplit does not work and how to fix it?

Perl 5.8.8 on RHEL 5.9.

Comment: `perl -F/ /` is what you want. But it won't help with preserving multiple spaces. Please give an example.

Comment: Does not work. Returns null output.

Comment: Try adding `-MO=Deparse` and see what the difference is

Comment: From `perldoc perlrun`: "`-Fpattern` specifies the pattern to split on if `-a` is also in effect. The pattern may be surrounded by `//`, `""`, or `''`, otherwise it will be put in single quotes. **You can’t use literal whitespace in the pattern.**" (emphasis added)

Comment: Also, `' '` acts like `/\s+/`, except it strips leading whitespace. If you *don't* need that, perhaps you should consider using something more suitable to what you need. Which is something we don't actually know anything about. But `/ /` and `/\s+/` is quite different

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Workarounds to the "you can't put literal whitespace in the pattern" restriction:

```
perl -F\\x{20} ...
perl -F\\040   ...
```

Comment: @PhilippeA.: I'm pleased that you have an answer but I'm not clear how it answers your question. If the problem was that you need multiple blanks preserving then this doesn't do that - it just fills `@F` with several null strings. Please would you explain your application a little better?

Comment: @PhilippeA.: Also, `perl -aF'chr(20)'` does a `split /chr(20)/` which can't be what you wanted?

Comment: Borodin: I have found my mistake and deleted my prior comment.

Comment: @Borodin: mob solution works for me because I don't need to access individual array fields. I only need to have my consecutive blanks when I print in scalar context. Very short story: I am comparing strings in a shell based test suite.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about the number of intervening spaces then you need to *capture* those as well as the data. I think the equivalent of `split /(\s+)/` is what you want.

With a data file that looks like

```
  x  x  x
```

(thats `"\x20\x20x" x 3`)

and a command line like

```
perl -MData::Dump -F/(\x20+)/ -anE"dd \@F" data.txt
```

you get this output

```
["", "  ", "x", "  ", "x", "  ", "x\n"]
```

Does that help?